# Python requests.get > ERROR: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new to python and come across below problem.
I had code like below for reading data to csv from web:

```
    for page in range(1, int(page_number) + 1):
        print(type(category_id))
        params = (
            ('categoryName', category_id),
            ('currentPage', page),
            )

        responsee = requests.get(
            'https://www.website.com/DesktopModules/BrowseV2/API/BrowseV2Service/GetProductsInformation',
            headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)


        data = responsee.json()

        for product in data["products"]:
            prdUrl = "https://www.website.com" + product["PrdUrl"]
            name = product["DisplayName"]
            code = product["ItemCode"]
```

The problem is that sometimes caterory_id is blank then website is returning message:

```
"ERROR: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"
```

How I can handle this exception ?
I dont want to do it by validating category_id but by properly reading response from website via requests?
Thanks

Comment: Try this line `if not category_id: continue` just after `print(type(category_id))` or kicking out `print(type(category_id))`

Comment: that seems to be working :)
do you know how to do it on response message ?